# CakePHP Validation

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

How do I show the messages when using the CakePHP validation? As I creating the input fields manually using `input()` instead using the shorthand `form()` helper.

e.g. Form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('id' => 'loginform', 'type' => 'post',
'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'))); ?>

    <fieldset id="login">

        <ul class="clearfix">               
            <li id="li-username">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array( 'label' => array('class' => 'placeholder', 'text' => 'Email address or username') )); ?>
            </li>
            <li id="li-password">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array( 'type' => 'password', 'label' => array('class' => 'placeholder', 'text' => 'Password') )); ?>
                <span id="iforgot"><?php echo $this->Html->link('?', 
                array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'forgotpassword'),  array('title' => 'Forgot your password?')); ?></span>
            </li>
            <li id="li-submit">
                <button type="submit" title="Log in">Log in &#9658;</button>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

and this is my validation in the user model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'The email is not valid'
        ),
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please enter an email'
        )
    )
);
```

However the validation error messages don't show?

**EDIT:
I tested this on my register form at /users/add/ and it works so it seems that the auto validation does not work with the login method???? How do I add validation for the login form then :/**

Comment: Cameron can you  post your users/add action code?

You can see what has failed validaiton by dumping the invalidfields variable.

    pr($this->User->invalidFields);

Answer (score 1):

The validation is actually stored in the model object. I'm not entirely sure off-hand how to access the errors, but I think its in $this->User->validationErrors.

Have a look at the [model api](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model) for more information.

For logging in, use the [auth component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1261/login). If you'd rather not, then just get the user from the db and display an error using $this->Session->SetFlash() if the user doesn't authenticate.

Comment: according to the book though it should automatically show the errors below the input field.

Comment: yes it does. Why aren't you using the $form->input() ? also, maybe post some code from your controller where you're trying to validate the form.

Comment: I do use the form input (see code in OP) but I don't think that's the issue as it works on the register form but not the login form (see edit)

Comment: Validation kicks in when you're trying to validate or save to the database. I assume you're just trying to authenticate on the login form and not write to the database. Thats probably why the validation doesn't work. You can tweak it by populating the $this->User->validationErrors yourself if login fails.

Comment: Hi can you show an example of how to do this for the login? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can show your code login function?
I think in your code that have redirect in-case validate false
If you use $this->redirect() it'll not show validate messages :)

Answer (score 0):

First you check your post data is going to validate function.you can simple check this in your else condition like this :

```
$this->{$this->modelClass}->set($this->data);
if($this->{$this->modelClass}->validates(){
    //Save data in DB
}else{
   pr($this->{$this->modelClass}->validationErrors); // This will show your error message
}
```

You can also show error in your view.ctp file like this

```
    $errors = '';
    foreach ($this->validationErrors[$model] as $key =>  $validationError) { 
        $errors .= $this->Html->tag('li', $validationError[0]);
    }
    echo $this->Html->tag('ul', $errors,array('class' => 'error'));
```